# Favicon doesnt show transparency on android

Tags: android, transparency, favicon

I have a website, and when people visit it on android devices they can 'add shortcut on home screen', which places the favicon on the home screen.

The problem is that the image looses its transparency and whats supposed to be transparent becomes white.
I've checked the image, its transparent. And the transparency is properly displayed in the browser tab on laptops.

I'm displaying the favicon by putting a

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="path/theicon.png">
```

in the header.

How can I make the favicon display with transparency on android devices?

Comment: Which browser do you use to add to home screen? Chrome? Something else?

Comment: It's a browser called 'internet' on samsung galaxy s4.

Comment: Okay, then I agree with the proposed answer. Apart from Android Chrome, browsers tend to not support "add to home screen" icons, either partly or completely. Samsung default browser is one of them. I suggest you to keep your icon as it is, and keep an eye on your analytics: are most of your Android users using Chrome? Probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some launcher don't support transparent icon. they change transparent part to white (like MI launcher)

Comment: anything i can do to fix it?

Comment: Nothing that I know Sorry :( . But people using these launchers are used to non-transparent icons. You can stop worrying about it.

Comment: can i change which images become favicons depending on the device?